# Unable to Install Mylin connector plugin in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins, rakefile

I'm trying to install redmine_mylyn_connector-stable-2.8.zip plugin in Redmine. When I try to execute the Rake command it shows the below error. Can anyone help?

```
bash-4.1# rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
(in /data/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs)
Could not find gem 'libxml-ruby (>= 2.3.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've built the gemfile but it still shows the same error.

Comment: do you install gem `libxml-ruby` using `bundle install` command after specify it in `Gemfile`

Comment: Yes.but still showing same error

Comment: as per your error it is clearly state that it need `libxml-ruby` gem

Comment: I have tried build that libxml-ruby file but failed.Is there any other ways to do it?